# Google Data API

Tags: google-data-api

Two questions:

How do you get events from a specific Calendar? The following link gets events for your primary calendar: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user@gmail.com/private/full .

And how do you get a contact's birth date from the list of ContactEntry objects that is returned to you when using the ContactsService?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I am using the .NET class library, specifically C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should probably provide some of my findings in-case somebody else wants to know this. As far as getting the dates from public calendars are concerned, the CalendarEntry class contains a generic list of AtomLink objects. The very first one's AbsoluteUri property will provide you with the EventEntry objects for that calendar. Here is some sample code:

```
  foreach (CalendarEntry c in calendars)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(c.Title.Text);
    if (c.Links.Count > 0)
    {
      AtomLink link = c.Links[0];
      EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
      query.Uri = new Uri(link.AbsoluteUri);
      query.FutureEvents = true;

      // Tell the service to query:
      EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
      foreach (EventEntry entry in calFeed.Entries)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
        foreach (When w in entry.Times)
          Console.WriteLine("\t" + w.StartTime);
      }
    }
    else
      Console.WriteLine("...no data found.");

    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();
  }
```

I still don't know how to get the Contact's birth date :/ I'll have a look at that when I have more time.